# Как сделать чтобы пользователи не спамили боту telebot python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, sqlite3

Имеется бот-магазин с дб sqlite3, которая не многопоточная (я других дб не знаю). Если пользователь спамит боту, то бот крашится изза дб. Как сделать чтобы была как бы задержка перед новым использованием команды?

Код вставить не могу. Он слишком большой.

Comment: SQLite поддерживает одновременный доступ многих пользователей. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060772/sqlite-concurrent-access

Comment: Вообще пускать пользователя сразу на основную бд не очень круто, сделайте проверку на спам.

Comment: Если бот это один постоянно запущенный процесс, то прямо в нем сделать словарь с клиентами и отражать в нем кто когда последний раз писал. Принимать меры если таймаут еще не вышел а получена новая команда. Если процесс не постоянно в памяти или их несколько то использовать внешнее хранение такого же списка кто когда обращался с удалением тех у кого вышли таймауты, для этого удобно использовать Redis

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решить без смены дб не удалось. Сменил дб на MongoDB надеюсь всё будет норм...